# how to delete a phantom post in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a phantom post id (393) that I can't find through the dashboard. It's in the code and seems to be causing havoc. I'm trying to delete the post. I think I have the correct PHP code to do this?:

```
<?php wp_delete_post(393); ?>
```

But I don't know where to paste this code. Help please?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to load an image from the Media Library: Content Encoding Error -- The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that's probably the same method used by the backend to delete a post.

Perhaps try using phpadmin to delete the post from the database directly. This is a good reference: http://www.xarj.net/2008/how-to-mass-delete-posts-in-wordpress-phpmyadmin-sql/